# Implementing state-machines (ala generators) using iterators

Tags: c++, iterator, c++11, generator

Lately I have been needing to implement small classes that generate a bunch of numbers. It would be very convenient if C++ had generators like python, but unfortunately it is not so.

So I have been thinking of how to best implement these types of objects, for easy iteration and composition. When we think of iterators over containers, they essentially only hold the index to an element, and the bulk of the information is in the container itself. This allows for several iterators to be referencing different elements within a collection at the same time.

When it come to state machines, it becomes apparent that the iterator will have to hold the whole state as several iterators need to be able to be independent. In that sense, the state machine class is more of a "builder" of these iterators which are the actual state machines.

As a toy example I have implemented the range generator (ala `xrange` in python), that can be used in loops:

```
// using range-for from c++11
for (auto i : range<int>(1, 30)) {
    cout << i << endl;
}
```

The code can be found on [my bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org/KholdStare/quickndirty/src/f1f6f2994338/range/range.hpp).

That said, it is awkward to store the whole state within the iterator, since the `end()` iterator is created just for the sake of comparing the ending state, which wastes space if the state is a large collection of members.

Has there been anything done with simple linear state machines, and looping over them with iterators?

Comment: I don't understand what is awkward about your implementation. It only stores the current value and the value by which to increment the value.

Comment: "The code can be found on my bitbucket. " [Boost.Range](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/libs/range/doc/html/index.html) beat you [to it](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/libs/range/doc/html/range/reference/ranges/irange.html).

Comment: [Boost.Iterator](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/libs/iterator/doc/index.html#specialized-adaptors) also has some 'clever' iterators and supposedly makes it easier to define your own, which can in turn be used with Boost.Range. Although I don't have enough experience with it to comment on those claims.

Comment: Thanks for the pointers guys, I think I'll close the question. Boost.Iterators is basically what I was looking for to help me out.

Comment: @Alexander Kondratskiy: You can post it as an answer and accept it.

Comment: As a general comment, there is no alternative to storing the state of a generator once for each instance.  In languages that support generators natively (e.g. Python), the state is stored by the language for you, transparently, but it's still stored once for each instance of the generator.  However, there's an easy answer to the `end()` problem: you can use the pimpl idiom, and have iterators _point to_ the implementation of the generator; `end()` would simply have a null pointer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you support only forward iteration, you might be able to get away with using a different type for end() then for begin(). Here's the basic idea

```
class iterator;

class iterator_end {
  typedef ... value_type;
  ...

  iterator& operator++ () { throw ... }
  value_type operator* () { throw ... }
  bool operator== (const iterator& e) const { return e == *this; }
}

class iterator {
  typedef ... value_type;
  ..

  iterator& operator++ () { ... }
  value_type operator* () { ... }
  bool operator== (const iterator_end& e) const { return are_we_done_yet }
}

class statemachine {
  iterator begin() const { ... }
  iterator_end end() const { ... }
}
```

I've never tries this though, so I can't guarantee that this will work. Your state-machine's `iterator` and `const_iterator` typedefs will specify a different type than `end()` returns, which may or may not cause trouble.

Another possibility is to go with a variation on pimpl which uses `boost::optional`. Put the iterator state into a separate class, and store it within a `boost::optional` within the iterator. Leave the state unset for the iterator returned by `end()`. You won't save any memory, but you avoid heap allocations (boost::optional doesn't do any, it uses placement new!) and initialization overhead.